# Sending mail whenever POST request in API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I am using django and django-rest-framework to serve some API's. Vue.js is used to interact those API's as an frontend framework. I am able to send POST request data with the help of "Axios" and data is saving in django.

I want to send mail whenever a POST request occurs. Initially when I was using django-forms, sending mail was easy because I would send_mail just before form.save(). But now I am little bit confused

views.py

```
class StudentQueryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = StudentQuery.objects.all()
  serializer_class = StudentQuerySerializer

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    query=self.get_object()
    serializer = StudentQuerySerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      msg = "A new query has been added in Category" + str(query.category)
      msg += "\n Name: " + query.name
      msg += "\n Contact: " + str(query.contact)
      msg += "\n Subject: " + str(query.subjects)
      msg += "\n Standard: " + str(query.standard)
      msg += "\n Address: " + str(query.address)
      send_mail(emailSubject, message, emailFrom, emailList, fail_silently=False)
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I used this create method I got hit by Assertion error. Here is the traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /api/student-query/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/f1uk3r/Coding/edhusk-project/edhusk2/clientforms/views.py", line 21, in create
    query=self.get_object()
  File "/home/f1uk3r/.virtualenvs/edhusk-project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 94, in get_object
    (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
AssertionError: Expected view StudentQueryViewSet to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

routers.py

```
from clientforms.views import  StudentQueryViewSet
router.register(r'student-query', StudentQueryViewSet)
```

urls.py

```
from .routers import router
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: You need to show your URLs. It's not clear what you have done here; this is a viewset, but the error suggests you have declared it like a normal view. In any case, this has nothing to do with sending email.

Comment: edited question to add routers.py and urls.py. I am kind of following this blog https://ahackersday.com/blog/building-a-todo-app-using-vue-js-and-django-as-the-backend/

Comment: But what are you expecting `self.get_object()` to do? You're calling the URL "/api/student-query/", there is no object ID so no object to get. Don't you want to get the data from the serializer instead?

Comment: So you are saying i should use something like self.serializer_class(data=request.data)? I am not sure but i thought it will give me all the data in that instance. I am still new in programming so i copied what was in rest-framework documentation. You are absolute right that i should get data from the serializer, but how do i do that?

Comment: No, I didn't say that at all. You already have a serializer instance. When you call `serializer.save()` it returns the saved object. Surely that's what you want to use when sending the email?

Comment: Yes, i want to use data from saved object to mail. The whole object-method business hurts my brain, some times its hard for me to figure out which objects means what. Instead of query.contact i should call serializer.contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the call to `get_object` and assign the result of the serializer save to `query`.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = StudentQuerySerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      query = serializer.save()
      msg = "A new query has been added in Category" + str(query.category)
      ...
```

(Note, `query` is a confusing name to use here; I've kept it for consistency with the rest of your code, but really you should use something like `obj`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for having patience when i was not able to explain what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Another option is leave the viewset and serializer as they are - without overriding the create method to send the email.

And use signals instead.

you can register a listener for `pre_save` or `post_save` signal. And send email from there.

So everytime new `StudentQuery` is created and another object updated - it will run your listener to send the email.

Comment: I have read about signals, but i went with sending mail through views because it seems more intuitive

Comment: @f1uk3r  yes ,both have pros and cons. Just wanted to point out another possible approach.